# Multi Drag Drop in WPF -- Example/Sample/Tutorial?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am looking for an example or any ready made solution which I can integrate in my existing application and use the multi drag and drop functionality. Most of the solutions I found on internet doesn't work well when it comes to dragging and dropping of multiple items from a control like ListBox to another ListBox. Can anyone point me to a solution? I am using WPF - C# - MVVM

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Check if this helps

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_MultiSelect_DragDrop.aspx

**EDIT**

The [GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop library](http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/) is a drag'n'drop framework for WPF. It has the following features:

```
* Works with MVVM : the logic for the drag and drop can be placed in a ViewModel. No code needs to be placed in codebehind, instead attached properties are used to bind to a drag handler/drop handler in a ViewModel.
* Works with multiple selections.
* Can drag data within the same control to re-order, or between controls.
* Works with TreeViews.
* Can insert an item into a collection, or drop one item onto another.
* Can display Adorners to give the user visual feedback of the operation in progress.
* Has sensible defaults so that you have to write less code for common operations.
```

Give it a try

Comment: I can't use this in MVVM.. whole code is in code behind.. plus the example is showing only drag and drop within a single list box

Comment: I already have tried this solution.. it's description says it does but in actual multiple drag and drop doesn't work.. try it yourself to verify and let me know what you found out

Comment: you can discuss issues over here http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/issues/list