# Drag and drop example?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop

I have a simple question,I searched the internet already but i can't really find an example. I just need something simple: I have 2 listviews and i want to have drag and drop. But it has to be in WPF and MVVM. The examples i found weren't that clear.I have problems with handling the events. Someone who can help me out and give a good link to a nice example or tutorial?

Comment: See if this is related to your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646751/multi-drag-drop-in-wpf-example-sample-tutorial

Comment: you can visit example vb.net http://stackoverflow.com/a/10390737/1363514