# WPF Drag and Drop

Tags: wpf, vb.net, drag-and-drop

How to implement drag & drop for a WPF application? I could open 2 the same apps and drag an object from one to another. Here's what I want to drag:

```xaml
<Grid Width="100" Height="50">
 <Rectangle BackGround="Red"/>
 <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

The Grid has to look the same in the other app where it is dragged as the one from it was dragged. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Gong Solutions Drag and Drop successfully in the past, it's a very easy DLL to use. You can see a small sample of it here: [Gong Solutions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/gong-wpf-dragdrop.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Using a Behavior :

you’ll need markup like this:

```
<Window xmlns:i=
"clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:custom=
"clr-namespace:CustomBehaviorsLibrary;assembly=CustomBehaviorsLibrary >
```

example :

```
<Canvas>
<Rectangle Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Fill="Yellow" Width="40" Height="60">
</Rectangle>
<Ellipse Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="70" Fill="Blue" Width="80" Height="60">
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<custom:DragInCanvasBehavior></custom:DragInCanvasBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Ellipse>
<Ellipse Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="70" Fill="OrangeRed" Width="40" Height="70">
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<custom:DragInCanvasBehavior></custom:DragInCanvasBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Ellipse>
```

Answer (score -1):

**example WPF Drag and Drop : using vb.net 2010**

```
        <Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="mofakfree"
        Title="drop test " Height="359" Width="329">
        <Grid>
                <Label x:Name="label2" AllowDrop="True"  Margin="159,30,12,0" Background="#FF1900FF" Content="To Here" DragEnter="label2_DragEnter" Drop="label2_Drop" Height="51" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label x:Name="label1" AllowDrop="True"  Margin="26,30,158,240" Background="#FFDE2626" Content="source" MouseDown="label1_MouseDown"/>
        </Grid>
        </Window>
```

**vb.net code :**

```
 Class mofakfree



        Private Sub label1_MouseDown(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
            'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            Dim lbl As Label = CType(sender, Label)
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbl, lbl.Content, DragDropEffects.Copy)
        End Sub

        Private Sub label2_DragEnter(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.Windows.DragEventArgs)
            'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) Then
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy
            Else
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None
        End If

        End Sub

        Private Sub label2_Drop(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.Windows.DragEventArgs)
            'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            CType(sender, Label).Content = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)

        End Sub

    End Class
```