# How do I setup a WPF TreeView with the data bound items containing 2 lists of 2 different types?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I'm trying to create a WPF treeview control (in C#, but that's not that important) that displays a hierarchical list of items. In addition to that, each item in the tree has a list of "other items" of a *different type* that I'd also like displayed (as below).

```
+ Item1
    - OtherItem1
    - OtherItem2
    + Item2
        - OtherItem3
        - OtherItem4
        + Item3
    + Item4

  etc...
```

I'd like the whole thing to be databound and support drag and drop. I have the basic list involving only "Item" setup but I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to support the second list. If someone can even just point me in the direction of the type of ItemSource thingy I should be using that would help a lot.

Do I need a MultiBinding or something?  Here's what's I'm trying at the moment (but it's not working out).

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Bones}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <!-- 
        This Style binds a TreeViewItem to a BoneTreeViewModel. 
        -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Skeleton.BoneTreeViewModel}">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <MultiBinding>
                    <Binding Path="Name" />
                    <Binding Path="Components" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Where **Name** is just a string representing the name of Item and **Components** is the (flat, non hierarchical) ReadOnlyCollection of OtherItem.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

here's the xaml i use for treeviews

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Behaviors:TreeViewSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

and a simplified VM which you can use as the base class for your 2 types of VMs

```
public class TreeNodeViewModel
{
    public TreeNodeViewModel()
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeNodeViewModel>();
    }

    public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }


    public ObservableCollection<TreeNodeViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

and link to
[drag and drop answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350114/drag-and-drop-example-mvvm-wpf)

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks for taking the time to help me out. I did consider this option but it doesn't really solve the problem. I don't want the type "otheritem" to be hierarchical and have children. You're solution would mean that both item and otheritem are treated the same way in the tree view.

Comment: i use the above as a base to represent multiple types of items in my treeview.  Also i consider these nodes as "containers" specifically for the use in the treeview rather than try and force my VM and treeviews to work together in some complex way, so it is only the container that has the hierachy