# How to hold image onClick WPF Grid and drag to another position in GRID

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<UserControl x:Class="Chess_Interface.UserControls.PositionControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Chess_Interface.UserControls"
         xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Chess_Interface"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="450">


<Grid>
    <UniformGrid Rows="8" Columns="1" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Label Content="8" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="7" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="6" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
    </UniformGrid>
    <UniformGrid Rows="8" Columns="1" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Label Content="8" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="7" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="6" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
    </UniformGrid>

    <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="8" Width="400" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label Content="A" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="B" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="C" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="D" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="E" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="F" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="G" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="H" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
    </UniformGrid>
    <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="8" Width="400" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Label Content="A" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="B" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="C" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="D" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="E" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="F" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="G" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
        <Label Content="H" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" />
    </UniformGrid>

    <Grid x:Name="ChessBoard" Width="400" Height="400" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MouseLeftButtonDown="ChessBoard_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="ChessBoard_MouseLeftButtonUp"  >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" SharedSizeGroup="SizeGroup"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" Background="Brown"></Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7" Background="White"></Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="6" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="7" Background="Brown"></Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="6" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="7" Background="White"></Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="5" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="6" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="7" Background="Brown"></Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="4" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="5" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="6" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="7" Background="White"></Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="3" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="4" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="5" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="6" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="7" Background="Brown"></Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="3" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="4" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="5" Background="White"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="6" Background="Brown"></Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="7" Background="White"></Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**I have added images through code its a ChessBoard UI i just want to hold image and drop to another gird cell **

**in code behind i have mouseDown mouseUp events , i have 64 border images are moving completely fine on click one cell to another 
i just want to add drag and drop feature to it thanks in advance
**

Comment: you should better use `UniformGrid Columns="8" Rows="8"`. or `ItemsControl` with `UniformGrid`

Comment: You try to Drag and Drop your elements. See sample here [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350114/drag-and-drop-example)

Comment: I can't use xaml , I have done all functionalities by code behind , In Grid I have 64 border  i easily move images from one border to another onClick

Comment: I have Grid in that grid i have 64 border and i easily moving images from one border to another onMouseLeftDown and onLeftUp events i just want is there anything when i click on the images , i can hold image and drag to desire position and drop